# Nice coordinate presentation of the covering map $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry, covering-spaces, complex-manifolds

I would like to write down a nice coordinate presentation of the double cover map $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$, where $S^2$ carries a single complex coordinate $z$ as the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}P^1 \cong \mathbb{C} \cup \infty$ and we use affine coordinates $x=X/Z,y=Y/Z$ for the affine patch of $\mathbb{R}P^2 =\{[X:Y:Z]\}$ where $Z\neq 0.$

Ideally this map should behave nicely with these structures. For example map the two hemispheres separately to the whole real plane, map the equator to the line at infinity 2 to 1, and maybe map the point at infinity of the Riemann sphere to that of the projective plane.

I know that a disc is not isomorphic to a plane in the complex category, so I must not expect the map to be holomorphic.

Here’s what I tried.

Since this is a double cover it should be degree two. The most obvious candidate is $z \mapsto z^2.$ This is after all the double cover map for $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$. Maybe it extends natural to higher spheres. But no, it’s not a covering map at 0 and $\infty$. As a holomorphic map we knew this would not work.

One obvious way to identify antipodal points on a sphere is to map $z$ to $z\cdot A(z),$ where $A$ is the antipodal map, as this product manifestly identifies antipodal points. In coordinates $A(z)=-\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$, so our map candidate is $z\mapsto -\frac{z}{\bar{z}}$. Or $re^{i\theta} \mapsto -e^{2i\theta}$. This one does map the equator to the line at infinity 2 to 1.  But then the rest of the cylinder it collapses onto the equator. And not clear how to define it at the poles.

The map $\frac{z}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}$ is a nice map of the unit disc to the plane. It does appear to map the equator to the line at infinity, as desired. Actually it appears that this one is also invariant under the antipodal map.

I thought I had a reason that this map didn’t work, but actually now it appears to meet all my criteria. Is $\frac{z}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}$ actually the “nice” double cover map from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$? Is it obviously continuous and a local homeomorphism and 2 to 1 everywhere?

Comment: I asked for a map that sends both the point at infinity and the unit circle. That doesn’t make sense though. You want the unit circle to go to the line at infinity and the Riemann point at infinity to go to a finite point. Probably 0, which my candidate does.

Comment: Representing your mapping as $$z\mapsto(\operatorname{Re}z, \operatorname{Im}z, 1-|z|^{2})$$clarifies that the disk maps to part of a paraboloid and then (surjectively) to the projective plane. The outside of the unit disk maps to the projective plane minus one point (the image of the south pole). I haven't carefully checked details, but your formula does appear to have the properties you want.

Comment: You say that $z \mapsto z^2.$ is the the double cover map for $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$.  Don't you tacitly use the identification of $\mathbb{R}P^1$ with $S^1$ in this formula? What would it be without that?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Yes, that confusion was the barrier keeping me from seeing the answer. To view $z\mapsto z^2$ as the double cover map of $\mathbb{RP}^1$ requires you to to identify the projective line with a circle. It's basically assuming the answer. If you don't identify, then you're left with just $z\mapsto [z]$ (the linear subspace containing $z$), and you arrive at Joshua's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ the double cover is $(x,y,z)\mapsto [x:y:z]$. An identification of $S^2$ with the Riemann sphere is

$$\left[z:w\right]\in \mathbb{CP}^1\mapsto \left(\frac{2zw^\ast}{|w|^2+|z|^2},\frac{-|w|^2+|z|^2}{|w|^2+|z|^2}\right)\in \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}^3\tag 1$$

where the image of this map is $S^2$.

On the affine patch $\mathbb{CP}^1\setminus\{(1:0)\}\cong \mathbb{C}$, it is

$$z\in \mathbb{C}\mapsto \left(\frac{2z}{1+|z|^2},\frac{-1+|z|^2}{1+|z|^2}\right)\in \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}^3\tag 2$$

So, composing the homeomorphism $\mathbb{CP}^1\xrightarrow{\sim} S^2$ with the double cover, we get

$$[z:w]\mapsto \left[2\Re(zw^\ast):2\Im(zw^\ast):-|w|^2+|z|^2\right]\tag 3$$

Or again, in the affine coordinates this is

$$z\mapsto \left(\frac{2\Re(z)}{|z|^2-1},\frac{2\Im(z)}{|z|^2-1}\right)\tag 4$$

*Note.* I obtained $(2)$ by computing the stereographic projection. The obvious completion of $(2)$ to all of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is $(1)$.

Comment: "the double cover map in global coordinates is just $(x,y,z) \mapsto [x:y:z]$". that's so simple and obvious. I actually realized that fact while thinking about how the equator will map into the line at infinity. But for some reason still did not occur to me to start the whole question from this map on all of $S^2$ to $\mathbb{RP}^2$. And once you realize, you realize you have to use the stereographic projection in the opposite direction than I did, and then you're done. This answer was great, thank you.

Comment: So you have $z \mapsto \dfrac{2z}{\lvert z \rvert^2-1}$ which is practically that what the OP guessed.

Comment: What happens in (4) for $\lvert z \rvert = 1$? Shouldn't the formula work for all $z \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: @KritikerderElche the equator on $S^2$, defined by $|z|=1$, is mapped to the line at infinity in $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: @PaulFrost An overall scale doesn't change the answer, so I would say that Joshua's answer and my guessed candidate function are actually the same answer. But Joshua's answer explained _why_ (it's just stereographic projection of the tautological quotient map), whereas my guess was just a shot in the dark pulled off a wikipedia page about the uniformization theorem. That makes all the difference.

Comment: But then there is a problem. The map $z \mapsto \dfrac{2z}{\lvert z \rvert^2-1}$ maps $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$ to the single  point at infinity with respect to the affine patch $\mathbb R^2$ of $\mathbb RP^2$, not to the line at infinity in $\mathbb RP^2$. So don't you need a separate definition on $S^1$ and check continuity? The core of the problem seems to be that there is no reasonable map from the affine patch $\mathbb C \subset \mathbb CP^1$ to the affine patch $\mathbb R^2 \subset \mathbb RP^2$.

Comment: @KritikerderElche In homogenous coordinates, the map is $[2x,2y,|z|^2-1]$ which makes it clear that at $|z|=1$ you map to the line at infinity. Not to a single point. Also it's manifestly continuous. Going back to the affine patches, we are double covering the interior and the exterior of the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{C}P^1$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2\subset \mathbb{R}P^2.$

Comment: so maybe you can say there's no reasonable map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but what we have instead is $\mathbb{C}\setminus S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Given the context that's probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: @KritikerderElche if you have some issue with the affine patch, just use the global definition $[z:w]\mapsto [2\Re(zw^\ast):2\Im(zw^\ast):-|w|^2+|z|^2]$, i.e. $(3)$ in my answer.

Comment: This comment prompted another question. When looking for maps based on reasonable affine maps between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, the most obvious map is the identity map on the plane. Can identity map be extended to the respective projective spaces? Obviously not as a map from $\mathbb{C}P^1\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ since there's no continuous way to map one point at infinity into the line at infinity. But the other way? Collapse the entire line to a point, and you have a map from $\mathbb{R}P^2\to\mathbb{C}P^1$. This appears to be continuous, but that can't exist for pi1 reasons, right?

Comment: Ok actually that continuous map does exist, in homogeneous coordinates it's just $[x:y:z]\mapsto [x+iy:z]$. While it's true that there are no nontrivial maps from $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\to \pi_1(S^2)$, there's no contradiction here, because this map sends a fundamental loop to a great circle, which is contractible. The map is nontrivial, but its image on pi1 is trivial. This map is discussed in a more homotopy theoretic way in this answer by Tyrone: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063842/16490